# Connection to an instance-specific SQL Server DB from a Rails Application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, heroku

We are connecting to a SQL Server application from a Rails 4 application running on Heroku. Everything used to work fine. We used [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) to give us a static IP address we could then allow through our Firewall. A simple ENV variable was used on heroku to store the SQL Server request URI like so:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'tiny_tds'

# customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(ENV["MS_SQL_DATABASE_URL"])
  ..
end

MS_SQL_DATABASE: sqlserver://username:password@176.32.98.166/DATABASE1?autocommit=true&timeout=5000
```

Now this all works fine, until the database was updated to a newer version and `Database1` now moved to a new instance called `Instance1`. So in order to connect to the upgraded database we need to specify an instance name as part of our connection uri.

Specifying the instance name works locally when we VPN into the network and use the following connection URL

```
MS_SQL_DATABASE: sqlserver://username:password@192.168.168.1/DATABASE1?autocommit=true&timeout=5000&dataserver=192.168.168.1%5CINSTANCE1
```

Note we are using the dataserver property and specifying the full path to the server. The server name inside the network is known as `192.168.168.1` and also as `server1`. But from outside the network (on Heroku) we cannot address it like that.

What will be the proper way to address the server name to specify the instance name to allow a connection from heroku?

Is it even possible to do this? If not, what are some alternatives?